# Why does my phone return HTTP 403 error, even though the same code works in emulator?

Tags: php, wamp, adk

I am using WAMP.

httpd.conf is given below:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

PHPMyadmin alias

```
alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.4/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted

    <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require all granted
    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </ifDefine>
```

Comment: Please update your question with your version of Apache.

Comment: Are you trying to use phpMyAdmin from your phone?

Comment: I am using 2.4.23 version of Apache

Comment: No I am not using phpMyAdmin from phone

Comment: Turns title into question format. Makes it clear that code was tested on physical phone and emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Error is resolved

In virtual host i made this change

HostName test.test.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx/

```
<Directory /var/www/xxx>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```